# I can't install npm Mac m1 Monterey

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/ahmed/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ahmed/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ahmed/.npm/_logs/2021-11-11T23_07_31_793Z-debug.log
```

every time I tried to install rpm I get this error is it a path problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to use `npm install` for that *doesn’t* include a `package.json` file?

Answer (score 1):

If you're installing packages that you have added in `package.json` then be sure you're in the path where there is `package.json`

This error usually comes when you are not in a folder where `package.json` is present and you are trying to install packages using

```
npm install
```

Comment: I searched for package.json and I didn't find it in my Mac and when I right node.js in terminal it Said no such file or directory I'm trying to let a code I copied from a person to work in my computer but it asks me to download some packages and I couldn't .